# Send mail using SendGrid templates from Java

Tags: java, email, templates, sendgrid

I am using SendGrid for my transactional mails. When I just send the mail without using template using SendGrid JAVA classes, it works fine. However when I try to send it using the sendgrid template, it does not send a mail. My code is,

```
SendGrid sendGrid = new SendGrid(sendGridAPIKey);
SendGrid.Email sendGridMail = new SendGrid.Email();

sendGridMail.setTo(new String[] {email});
sendGridMail.setFrom("info@from.com");
sendGridMail.setSubject("Welcome to our portal");
sendGridMail.setText("Welcome Text");

sendGridMail.addFilter("templates", "enable", "1");
sendGridMail.addFilter("templates", "template_id", "TEMPLATE_ID");
sendGridMail.addSubstitution(":firstName", new String[] { firstName });
sendGridMail.addSubstitution(":email", new String[] { email });

SendGrid.Response response = sendGrid.send(sendGridMail);
```

The SendGrid template (with id TEMPLATE_ID) content looks as below,

```
Dear -firstName-,

Welcome to our portal. Your username is -email- and password is xxxxx. Please login to our portal with these credentials.

Thanks.
```

I am not sure what is going wrong as there is no exception thrown, the calls succeed, but the mail is not received.

- Is there any way to track the failures in SendGrid admin console?
- Is there any setting I need to do to get this working?
- Is there anything wrong in the code I am using?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Kari...